# Magento how to append the block

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have two modules. both modules needs to override the bundle **Render items**, and both doing well.But my problem is, while both modules are active any one of the render items are showing not another.But i want to show both items in view. Show can i append the block not override.

For example,

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <reference name="items">
        <action method="addItemRender">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>booking/sales_order_items_renderer</block>
            <template>email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="addItemRender">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>module1/bundle_sales_order_items_renderer</block>
            <template>module1/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="addItemRender">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>module2/bundle_sales_order_items_renderer</block>
            <template>module2/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</sales_email_order_items>
```

Above block adds extra items from module1 and module2 in sales order email. 
But module2 overrides module1, i need to show both options help me on this !

Answer (score 0):

One of suggestions would be to change or overrdie in subclass

```
addItemRender
```

function.

So it doesn't replaces the block, but adds it.

If I understood u correctly:

```
need to show both options
```

As for me, perhaps, I would redesign modules, so they won't disturb each other. Might be some observer-event pattern.